# CloudKit: delete CKSubscription is not working

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Hello i try to cancel a subscription on CloudKit.
So far i tried both CKModifySubscriptionsOperation and single removement by publicDB?.deleteSubscriptionWithID. My completionHandler gives me no error and an array of the deleted subscription ID's. So all seems to be ok.

But when i change a record i still get a push notification.
How to remove the subscriptions?

Here is the changed code:

```
func cancelCubscription(subscription:Subscriptions){
    self._animationDelegate?.beginAnimation()
    var subs = [String]()
    subs.append(subscription.daySubSignature!)
    subs.append(subscription.hdpSubSignature!)
    subs.append(subscription.noteSubSignature!)
    subs.append(subscription.planerSubSignature!)
    subs.append(subscription.subjectSubSugnature!)
    subs.append(subscription.teacherSubSignature!)
    subs.append(subscription.tldSubSignature!)

    // Create a CKModifyRecordsOperation operation
    let subscriptionOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: nil, subscriptionIDsToDelete: subs)

    subscriptionOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { (modifiedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs: [String]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        guard error==nil else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self._animationDelegate?.endAnimation()
                print(error!.localizedDescription)

                let title:String = "Alert_Cancel_CloudKit_Subscription_Error_Title".localized
                let message:String = error!.localizedDescription

                self._alertDelegate?.showAlert(title, message: message)
            })
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self._animationDelegate?.endAnimation()
            print("")
            print("- * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - *")
            print("Unscribe to CloudKit subscription success!")

            let title:String = "Alert_Cancel_CloudKit_Subscription_Success_Title".localized
            let message:String = "Alert_Cancel_CloudKit_Subscription_Success_Message".localized

            self._alertDelegate?.showAlert(title, message: message)

            for sub in deletedSubscriptionIDs!{
                print("Deleted Subscription: \(sub)")
            }

            subscription.tldSubSignature = "null"
            subscription.daySubSignature = "null"
            subscription.hdpSubSignature = "null"
            subscription.noteSubSignature = "null"
            subscription.planerSubSignature = "null"
            subscription.subjectSubSugnature = "null"
            subscription.teacherSubSignature = "null"
            subscription.subscribed = false
            Subscriptions.editSubsripction(subscription, context: self.appDel.managedObjectContext)
        })
    }

    // Add the operation to an operation queue to execute it
    self._publicDB!.addOperation(subscriptionOperation)
}
```

my subscriptions are still active:
[CloudKit Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSOsQ.png)

my log when subscribing:

```
- * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - *
CloudKit subscription success
teacherSubSignature = DE49AAFB-373C-49E5-8DC8-E81A977E7628
subjectSubSugnature = 3F06E054-D1B9-441E-AED3-CA947820D90C
daySubSignature = 8FF9AC02-F177-4381-AA8D-08AFFDB0A578
hdpSubSignature = 811ABA9A-D31B-4661-B783-B5DF033FC5F4
tldSubSignature = 1C07C661-02A9-48F3-9B92-08F41433E179
planerSubSignature = 1C32F1F0-3647-4F57-BDEF-215A28F69039
hdpSubSignature = 59216B52-1A21-4666-950A-F8CDE44591D2
Subscription Edited in Core Data
```

and on delete subscription:
    error = nil

```
- * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - *
Unscribe to CloudKit subscription success!

Deleted Subscription: 8FF9AC02-F177-4381-AA8D-08AFFDB0A578
Deleted Subscription: 59216B52-1A21-4666-950A-F8CDE44591D2
Deleted Subscription: 811ABA9A-D31B-4661-B783-B5DF033FC5F4
Deleted Subscription: 1C32F1F0-3647-4F57-BDEF-215A28F69039
Deleted Subscription: 3F06E054-D1B9-441E-AED3-CA947820D90C
Deleted Subscription: DE49AAFB-373C-49E5-8DC8-E81A977E7628
Deleted Subscription: 1C07C661-02A9-48F3-9B92-08F41433E179
Subscription Edited in Core Data
```

Comment: how are you getting the subscription to delete? did you check how many subscriptions you have (duplicates)?

Comment: i do not have duplicates my CloudKit dashboard shows only the right types and amount. but still after delete action.

Comment: Did you check to make sure there are no pending notifications? Did you make sure that, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this isn't the definitive answer, but need to put some code down and the comments are too short. What does it all mean; the first method fetches any outstanding notifications, the second makes sure you the same page as regarding their attention.

You need to make sure you got something like place before deleting the subscriptions ideally.

Disclaimer this is demo code; and I haven't tested it extensively. But it should work.

```
func fetchSubsInPlace() {
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.ch")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDB.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler({subscriptions, error in
        for subscriptionObject in subscriptions! {
            let subscription: CKSubscription = subscriptionObject as CKSubscription
            print("subscription \(subscription)")
        }
    })
}

func fetchNotificationChanges() {
    let operation = CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: nil)

    var notificationIDsToMarkRead = [CKNotificationID]()

    operation.notificationChangedBlock = { (notification: CKNotification) -> Void in
        // Process each notification received
        if notification.notificationType == .Query {
            let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
            let reason = queryNotification.queryNotificationReason
            let recordID = queryNotification.recordID

            print("reason \(reason)")
            print("recordID \(recordID)")
            // Do your process here depending on the reason of the change

            // Add the notification id to the array of processed notifications to mark them as read
            notificationIDsToMarkRead.append(queryNotification.notificationID!)
        }
    }

    operation.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = { (serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken?, operationError: NSError?) -> Void in
        guard operationError == nil else {
            // Handle the error here
            return
        }

        // Mark the notifications as read to avoid processing them again
        let markOperation = CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: notificationIDsToMarkRead)
        markOperation.markNotificationsReadCompletionBlock = { (notificationIDsMarkedRead: [CKNotificationID]?, operationError: NSError?) -> Void in
            guard operationError == nil else {
                // Handle the error here
                return
            }
        }

        let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
        operationQueue.addOperation(markOperation)
    }

    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}


}
```

Comment: This sounds good. Because i observed that i get more than one push sometimes. Seems i have prnding ones

Comment: Ok it seem to be well now. I don't know how many subscriptions i have made during test setup, but after resetting the deployment environment it seem to work also without marking the notifications to read. THX for all anwers