# How do i delete cksubscription in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, cksubscription

I'm sorry, but I can't find the answer in plain English, or at least every answer I see assumes I have a certain amount of knowledge that must not have. I just need to delete a `CKSubscription`. How do I do this? All tips and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CKModifySubscriptionOperation

Comment: I can't find example code in objective-c for this, official Apple documents don't seem to describe it in enough detail.

Comment: Oops - typo. It's `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation`. That should help you find examples. BTW - why do you need a specific example? Once you know how to use any of the CloudKit operations, you can use any of them since they all basically work the same way.

Comment: thanks! but I'm still lost because i have very hard times with syntax, what lines of code would i actually type out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017656/cloudkit-delete-cksubscription-is-not-working

Comment: yes but isn't that in swift? ill try to figure out it's objective-c equivalent. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have the subscriptionID of the subscription you want to delete, you should first fetch all of the subscriptions and figure out the subscriptionID of the subscription you want to delete:

```
[[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<CKSubscription *> * _Nullable subscriptions, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        //do your logic to find out which subscription you want to delete, and get it's subscriptionID
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
}];
```

Then, now that you have the subscriptionID, simply delete it:

```
CKModifySubscriptionsOperation *operation = [[CKModifySubscriptionsOperation alloc] initWithSubscriptionsToSave:nil subscriptionIDsToDelete:YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID];

operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray <CKSubscription *> * __nullable savedSubscriptions, NSArray <NSString *> * __nullable deletedSubscriptionIDs, NSError * __nullable operationError) {
    //handle the results when the operation has completed
};

[[[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] addOperation:operation];
```

Don't forget to always handle all the possible errors properly.

Comment: Thanks so much Roger!